# Are any of those quotient rings isomorphic to other well known rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis, ring-theory, convolution

(1) Let $C_b(\mathbb{R})$ be the ring (with pointwise multiplication and addition) of bounded continuous functions.

Let $I_0=\{f_{(x)} \in C_b(\mathbb{R}) \space | \space lim_{x \to \pm \infty}f_{(x)} = 0  \}$ be an ideal.

**Is $C_b(\mathbb{R})/I_0$ isomorphic to any other well known ring?**

(2) Let $F(\mathbb{R})$ be the set of all absolutely integrable differentiable functions. $F(\mathbb{R})$ is an rng (without identity) under the operations of addition and convolution.

Let $I \subset F(\mathbb{R})$ be the subset of functions with bounded derivatives. For any $f \in I$ and $g \in F(\mathbb{R})$ the following holds:

$$(f*g)'=f'*g$$

$f'$ is bounded by definition of $I$ and $g$ is absolutely integrable which implies that $f'*g$ is bounded (It's pretty likely i got a mistake here somewhere). Thus $f*g \in I$ and convolution is commutative so $I$ is an ideal.

**What does $F(\mathbb{R})/I$ look like?**

Comment: With regards to (1), you might find it helpful to recall that, canonically, $C_b(\mathbb{R}) \cong C(\beta \mathbb{R})$, where $\beta \mathbb{R}$ denotes the Stone–Čech compactification of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić Thanks! I didn't know that, I'll try and see if it helps.

Comment: Yes, (1) seems to be something like $C(\beta {\bf R} \setminus {\bf R})$. Essentially, any function with non-trivial or non-existent limit corresponds to a new point in the compactification.

Comment: @Marek You're right. $I_0 = C_0(\mathbb{R})$, the non-unital commutative $C^\ast$-algebra of continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ vanishing at infinity, so that by the Gel'fand–Naimark dictionary,
$$
 C_b(\mathbb{R})/I_0 \cong C(\beta\mathbb{R})/C_0(\mathbb{R}) \cong C(\beta\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{R}),
$$
the Corona algebra of $C_0(\mathbb{R})$.